# Python 3 - How do I use tkinter progressbar with a bat file?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

So far, the bat runs but the progress bar doesn't. How do I connect the two with each other? Here is the image of the output. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytZ6F.jpg

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from subprocess import call

def runBat():
    call("mp3.bat")

root = Tk()

photobutton3 = PhotoImage(file="smile.png")
button3 = Button(root, image=photobutton3, command=runBat)
button3.grid()

pbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
pbar.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does the batch file print the percent done?

Comment: The batch file does continuously tell me how much percentage is completed.

Comment: What format is the percentage in?

Answer (score 0):

## This answer ended up not working. The question is still open.

Try this:

```
import subprocess
import threading
import ctypes
import re
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class RunnerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, command):
        super(RunnerThread, self).__init__()
        self.command = command
        self.percentage = 0
        self.process = None
        self.isRunning = False
        
    def run(self):
        self.isRunning = True
        self.process = process = subprocess.Popen(self.command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
        while True:
            #Get one line at a time
            #When read() returns nothing, the process is dead
            line = b""
            while True:
                c = process.stdout.read(1)
                line += c
                if c == b"" or c == b"\r": #Either the process is dead or we're at the end of the line, quit the loop
                    break
            if line == b"": #Process dead
                break
            #Find a number
            match = re.search(r"Frame\=\s(\d+\.?(\d+)?)", line.decode("utf-8").strip())
            if match is not None:
                self.percentage = float(match.group(1))
        self.isRunning = False
                
    def kill(self): #Something I left in case you want to add a "Stop" button or something like that
        self.process.kill()


def updateProgress():
    progressVar.set(rt.percentage) #Update the progress bar
    if rt.isRunning: #Only run again if the process is still running.
        root.after(10, updateProgress)

def runBat():
    global rt
    rt = RunnerThread("mp3.bat")
    rt.start()
    updateProgress()

root = Tk()

photobutton3 = PhotoImage(file="smile.png")
button3 = Button(root, image=photobutton3, command=runBat)
button3.grid()

progressVar = DoubleVar()
pbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate', variable = progressVar)
pbar.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Basically, there's a thread that reads the data from the process and makes it available to a function that updates the progress bar every so often. You didn't mention the output's format, so I wrote it to use a regular expression to search for the first number and convert it.

Comment: May you help explain about the output file? Thank you for the help so far. I really do appreciate it for your dedicated efforts. The progress bar is not updating and I am not aware on how to grab the proper data for it. I am working with a mp3 converter. The data shows time completed out of a total mp3 file. Example: 1 minute completed, 2 minute completed, etc.

Comment: @BHok I found a small typo in my code. I've fixed it. Try running it now.

Comment: The progressbar doesn't update, so I am still thinking it is because of the output.

Comment: @BHok Please post sample output from the batch file.

Comment: @BHok Oops, a regular expression typo. Also, the code assumes that a percentage is output, not a minute count. If the batch file also prints out the total time it will take at the start, I can make it work, but again, I need to know the format.

Comment: It's the last line. I'm using a ffmpeg encoder to convert mp3 files to mp4.

Comment: @BHok That changes things quite a bit. I'll modify the code slightly. Try the new version and see if it works.

Comment: @BHok I changed it so it shows the frame it's on. See if that actually updates it (it will go off the end quickly). If it does, I might be able to get it to work. If it doesn't, I don't think it's possible. The batch file updating the info in place makes a huge difference.

Comment: It doesn't update, I watched the whole batch file run, but thank you for the hard efforts. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: One last possibility. Try adding `print(line)` before the line that starts with `match =` and see if it prints anything.

Comment: @BHok Do you want me to delete my answer, since it did not work? (You'll want to move the imgur link you posted to the question text if so.)

Comment: Good idea, I moved the image to the question. I believe your answer has great value, as it helps contribute to the overall question (people can see what has been attempted already). Though, best to label the answer that it didn't work out in the end.