# Python 3 - Why is my progressbar not working when calling a bat?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I click on the button, but the progress bar is not moving. The batch file works perfectly though.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from subprocess import call

def runBat():
    p.start()
    call ("mp3.bat")


root = Tk()

photobutton3 = PhotoImage(file="smile.png")
button3 = Button(root, image=photobutton3, command=runBat)
button3.grid()

p = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='indeterminate')
p.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you read [my answer to your first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836875/python-3-how-do-i-use-tkinter-progressbar-with-a-bat-file/43846792#43846792)?

Comment: I did, but this is an indeterminate progress bar.

Comment: The problem is that `call()` suspends execution to run the command. Try making `runBat()` start a thread that calls mp3.bat.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you so much!